# "Unspecified Type" in Structured Data Testing Tool

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I have recently written json schema for my client's local business with multiple locations. I have run it through Google's Structured Data Testing Tool, but I have noticed that it is defined as "unspecified type" rather than `LocalBusiness`.

I am also trying to implement this schema onto my client's WordPress site via Google Tag Manager and it has not seemed to work (I am guessing that this is because it is unspecified type rather than `LocalBusiness`?).

[image: Unspecified type screenshot]

Comment: Post the underlying JSON please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn’t post your JSON-LD, but from the output of Google’s SDTT, I would guess that this is the reason:

You’re using `graph` instead of `@graph`. Without the `@`, it gets interpreted as a Schema.org property (which doesn’t exist), not as a way defined in JSON-LD to provide multiple top-level items.

So instead of something like

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "graph": 
  [
    {
       "@type": "Organization"
    },
    {
       "@type": "LocalBusiness"
    }
  ]
}
```

you need to have something like

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@graph": 
  [
    {
       "@type": "Organization"
    },
    {
       "@type": "LocalBusiness"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the issue. I was wondering if you could help with my next issue. I have used google tag manager to implement my schema, but when I run the website in SDTT it does not come up with the LocalBusiness schema?

Comment: @DawnLimbu: Please ask a new question about this -- each question should only be about one topic (I can’t help you, though, as I don’t use GTM). --- If my answer here solved your issue, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark below the voting buttons.